# $A=(A \cap B) \cup(A \cap B^\mathsf{c}) $

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, proof-verification

I would like to know if this proof is correct. If not, what would I have to change to make it rigorous? This set equality seems really obvious, and because of that I am not sure if I have given enough arguments in my proof.

First, we need to prove that $A\subset(A \cap B) \cup(A \cap B^\mathsf{c})$, or $x \in A \Rightarrow x\in (A \cap B) \cup(A \cap B^\mathsf{c}) $

If x is in A, then x is contained in A and B or A and $B^\mathsf{c}$, since x can either be in B or $B^\mathsf{c}$ (by definition, $B^\mathsf{c}$ is the set of all elements not in B).

Now, we prove $(A \cap B) \cup(A \cap B^\mathsf{c}) \subset A$, or $x \in (A \cap B) \cup(A \cap B^\mathsf{c}) \Rightarrow x\in A$

If x is in A and $B^\mathsf{c}$ or in A and B, in either cases x is in A.

Comment: Or by distributive law $(A \cap B) \cup(A \cap B^\mathsf{c})=A \cap (B \cup B^\mathsf{c})=A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is sound, meaning that you cannot use the same kind of arguments to end up "proving" a wrong statement.

I personally would phrase your first argument slightly differently:
Let $a \in A$. Assume $x \in B$, then $x \in A \cap B$, hence $x \in (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B^c)$, done. If $\neg x \in B$, then $x \in B^c$, thus $x \in (A \cap B^c)$, etc.

However, this is mostly aesthetic taste. In order to get a more rigorous proof, you will need to commit to both a proof system and some particular set of axioms; and these then determine its shape. For most purposes though the present form should suffice.